# Changed name of user directory now rails command not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I'm using OSX and I wanted to change my username, so I followed the official Apple directions and used mv to change the name of my directory in /Users, then created a new user from the Users & Groups menu with the same name.

The name change was successful and I've retained my documents and apps but for some reason my computer doesn't think rails is installed.

Do I have to add something back to a path variable?

Edit: Brew Doctor revealed that it seems to be an ownership issue and told me to chown several directories in usr/local/

Are there any other important directories I should change the ownership on?  I thought creating the new user would have done this for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've enabled root user.

- From the Apple menu choose System Preferences.
- From the View menu choose Users & Groups.
- Click the lock and authenticate as an administrator account.
- Click Login Options.
- Click the "Edit..." or "Join..." button at the bottom right.
- Click the "Open Directory Utility..." button.
- Click the lock in the Directory Utility window.
- Enter an administrator account name and password, then click OK.
- Choose Enable Root User from the Edit menu.
- Enter the root password you wish to use in both the Password and
  Verify fields, then click OK.

Comment: I enabled root user, logged in as root, changed the name again to test it out but I still don't have permission